# Loop through MySQL table in order. If value is 0 store cell value next to it. If not 0 update to stored value

Tags: mysql

I've tried a few PROCEDURES and LOOPS, but i'm having trouble getting my results.

I have a table of 19,000 records that looks like this:

```
id | seq | custom_id
 1 |  0  | 123
 2 |  0  | 124
 3 |  1  | NULL
 4 |  0  | 125
 5 |  1  | NULL
 6 |  2  | NULL
 7 |  3  | NULL
```

My goal is:

```
id | seq | custom_id
 1 |  0  | 123
 2 |  0  | 124
 3 |  1  | 124-1
 4 |  0  | 125
 5 |  1  | 125-1
 6 |  2  | 125-2
 7 |  3  | 125-3
```

So if seq is 0 it will have a custom ID.  if seq is not 0 I would like to get the custom id and concat -seq to the end.

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: Pls show what you have tried so far and what went wrong with that attempt.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya -- 5.5.61-cll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In a [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html), we can get the previous (and closest) `custom_id` value where the `seq` is 0.
- Now, we simply need to use [`Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to concatenate the previous `custom_id` value with the current row's `seq` value, to get the new `custom_id`.

Try the following query to **Select** the data (**[DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b5NFksoT8d5GqFNtc4NVx8/0)**):

```
SELECT
  t1.id, 
  t1.seq, 
  CASE WHEN t1.seq = 0 THEN t1.custom_id 
       ELSE CONCAT((SELECT t2.custom_id 
                    FROM your_table AS t2 
                    WHERE t2.id < t1.id AND 
                          t2.seq = 0 
                    ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1), '-', t1.seq)
  END AS custom_id 
FROM your_table AS t1
```

---

However, based on your comments, it seems that you are interested in **Updating** the `custom_id` column at once. In MySQL, using subquery on the same table (which is being updated as well), is possible via [Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) approach.

We determine the modified `custom_id` for `id` where `seq <> 0` in a sub-select result set (Derived table), and then Join it back to the main table for update.

Try the following for **Updating** the data (**[DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b5NFksoT8d5GqFNtc4NVx8/1)**):

```
UPDATE  
 your_table AS tab 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    t1.id, 
    CONCAT((SELECT t2.custom_id 
            FROM your_table AS t2 
            WHERE t2.id < t1.id AND 
                  t2.seq = 0 
            ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1), 
            '-', t1.seq) AS custom_id 
  FROM your_table AS t1 
  WHERE t1.seq <> 0
) AS dtab ON dtab.id = tab.id 
SET tab.custom_id = dtab.custom_id 
WHERE tab.seq <> 0;
```

Comment: This works great as a select, and much simpler and easier than before.  My goal is to update the custom_ids so it is correctly stored in the DB. Sorry I left that off in the original request.

Comment: @Kyle same query can be modified to use as Update.

Comment: Thank you! I am kind of new to CASE but everything I have done in the past puts my update before the CASE.  Can I update within the ELSE only?

Comment: @Kyle check the updated answer please; check the second part (below the horizontal rule), for updating the data at once.